# Are these two sample approaches equally random?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a collection of words, and I want to choose one of them randomly.

I can sample the collection and get a word as the result.

I can also do this:

1. Take first word as the result.
2. For every word, flip a coin, and choose whether to skip it or
   overthrow the result.

After iterating over the whole collection, I will have randomly selected a word.

Are these two strategies equivalent in terms of unbiased randomness?

Comment: If in the collection there are N words, then "chances" (in the second method) that you'll end with your first word as the result are $ (\frac{1}{2})^{N-1} $

Comment: @Presage while sampling over the whole collection gives a $\frac{1}{N}$ chance to a word to be picked, right?

Comment: @gsamaras yes   $ $

Comment: @Gsamaras Exactly. In the second method, the earlier the word appear in the collection the less chances for it to being the result are.

Comment: @Presage Actually, I think that words in the "middle" are favorited

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Hmm, if you take a word on the position $K$ in the collection, then the probability of it being the result is $ (\frac{1}{2})^{N-K}$, cause it needs to "win" against every next word. So the farther from the beginning the word is, the less "enemies" to fight with has

Comment: @Presage You are right, I misunderstood the formulation: I thought that he starts at position $1$ and increments the counter with probability $0.5$ for every item. In this case it would have been a Binom. distribution and the item at position i would have been chosen with probability $\binom ni \cdot \left(\frac12\right)^n$.

Comment: From @Presage first comment I had the impression that the words last visited are the most favorited, while the words visited earlier, are less favorited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my short exchange with [@Presage](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/646860/):

Suppose you have the words $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$. Then, for $1\le i\le n$, we have:
The probability of choosing $w_i$ with the first method is $\frac1n$. The probability of choosing $w_i$ with the second method is equal to $\dfrac1{2^{n-i+1}}$.